# index position in ORDER BY (ranking position)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table enemies, one of the fields is a named "Power". I have power as index.

To list the enemies based in power I would use

```
SELECT * FROM enemies ORDER BY Power DESC
```

Now I want to show for a certain enemy the position based in power. Also I want to show the five enemies that are over and under that value.... but I dont want to read all the registers until the one that i'm interested (millions of registers).

something like:

```
enemy1 1111 
enemy2 1100 
... 
enemysearched 1000 
enemyn1 995 
.....
```

One option is to generate a rank column and calculate it often, but I just want to know if it is possible just with mysql at good speed.

Is it possible without reading the full table?

Comment: When the table isn't that big 1 or two million it should be that slow, to get the position, the only way i could think of is to save the rank and always keep it up-to-date, but that would cost much more that calculating it when it is needed.

Comment: I have in mind one idea... look for the value of the row, then another select order ASC with limit 5 and then  same query but changing the > for <= and limit 5 DESC

Comment: not in mysql that would cost more power performance than ranking it once., have you thought about  keeping the table in memory for the rank, it would cost because you must insert and update two tables the physical and that in memory, but it will be fast

Comment: I have tested the method that i told you before... 3 querys, first to search the value, then Select * FROM enemies WHERE Power>=$val ORDER BY Power ASC LIMIT 6 and another with Select * FROM enemies WHERE Power<$val ORDER BY Power DESC LIMIT 5.  It took 0.0005s to make the full table in my computer. Solution found.

Comment: It is not the solution :(, with that i know the table but not the position. To know the position you need to make a count with the number of values over your value

Answer (score 0):

> ...I want to show for a certain enemy the position based in power.

To find the position you can do:

```
select count(*) + 1
from enemies e 
join enemies f on f.power < e.power
where e.id = 1000 -- the base enemy
```

This query will perform an *Index Range Scan" engine operation so it should be faster than reading the table. Still it can be time consuming if there are many rows in the table.

> Also I want to show the five enemies that are over and under that value...

You can do:

```
select f.*
from enemies e 
join enemies f on f.power < e.power
where e.id = 1000 -- the base enemy
order by f.power desc
limit 5
union all
select f.*
from enemies e 
join enemies f on f.power > e.power
where e.id = 1000 -- the base enemy
order by f.power
limit 5
```

This query will perform two *Index Range Scan*. Both should be pretty fast all the time, since each will read 5 rows max.

Comment: I will check it later, but i dont know if it will be faster than the method that i wrote in comments. Anyways if it works and it is not too slow i will accept it. The position is not indexed and with 3 millions of register it can be slow, i will check and tell you. My solution is under 1ms.

Comment: @hamboy75 - Sounds the same.  Impaler's solution uses `PRIMARY KEY(id)` 3 times for a point query (very fast).  And `INDEX(power)` 3 times -- once will scan some portion of the index; the other two stop after 5 rows.